# iOS7 html form softkey Go button does nothing when onsubmit uses javascript window.open

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ios7

I need to submit form data in a _blank window to a URL that contains a couple different question marks in this format:

```
http://first--sample--url.com?http://second--sample--url.com?a=someUserInput&b=moreUserInput
```

The first URL does not allow requests sent with the POST method. Trying a form submission using a standard GET method, the URL is truncated after the first question mark, and I can't move the second URL to a hidden form field since it is not a name/value pair.

When testing the below code on the iOS6 simulator, it works fine -- both the submit button and the iOS softkey "Go" button (that appears on the soft keyboard while inputting text) execute the window.open call as intended.

Testing on iOS7 devices however, the softkey "Go" button does not allow the window.open to happen, even though the submit button works:

```
<form onsubmit="clickThrough(); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
    <input type="text" name="b" id="b">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    var url = "http://first--sample--url.com?http://second--sample--url.com?a={a}&b={b}",
        a = document.getElementById('a'),
        b = document.getElementById('b');

    function clickThrough() {
        var clickURL = url.split("{a}").join(a.value).split("{b}").join(b.value);
        window.open(clickURL, "_blank");
    }
</script>
```

Test the fiddle here on iOS7: http://jsfiddle.net/BC2Vv/5/embedded/result/

And edit the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BC2Vv/5/

Does anyone know a workaround for this in iOS7 so the softkey "Go" button will allow window.open to complete, or do you have any other solutions?

Thanks in advance!